# How to create Socket interface for dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, interface

How should I correctly create an interface for System.Net.Sockets.Socket (and in fact any other library class for which I don't have an Interface), so I can then use it with DI container?

The plan is to register the Socket service with IoC container:

```
...
services.AddScoped<ISocket, Socket>();
...
```

and then inject it wherever required.

I cannot see "Extract interface" in Quick refactoring menu.

So...

At the moment I wrapped Socket in another class for which I created an interface:

```
    interface ISocket
    {
        Socket Socket { get; }
    }
```

```
class TheSocket : ISocket
    {
        public Socket Socket { get; private set; }
        public TheSocket()
        {
            Socket = new(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }
    }
```

```
Register with container:
...
services.AddScoped<ISocket, TheSocket>();
...
```

And then I can inject it:

```
class ClassA : IClassA
    {
     public Socket Socket {get; private set;}

     public ClassA(ISocket isocket)
            Socket = iSocket.Socket;
    }
    ...
```

But I've got a feeling there must be more elegant way of doing this...

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Wrap it in a class that implements some interface, so you can mock it in your unit tests

Comment: An interface is normally used to hide implementation details and/or support different types of implememtations, e.g. for plugins, streams etc. Because there is only one `Socket` class, that is already implemented in the BCL, an additional `ISocket` interface makes not so much sense. You can create an `ISocketFactory` and `SocketFactory` pair to hide socket creation details, e.g. if you have several sockets.

Comment: @KBO that means my way is pretty much what you're saying. The class TheSocket : ISocket is in fact a factory for a Socket.